# Reading CMYK colors for graphic vectors from PDF

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I am trying to read CMYK colors from a PDF file for graphic vectors, I am using PDFBOX 2 to read the color space, The color space being returned is of type PDSeparation with alternative color space of PDDeviceCMYK, I didn't know how to proceed with PDDeviceCMYK, so I extracted the RGB colors and will convert them back to CMYK, but I didn't even find a function to convert them back to CMYK, so is there a way to extract the CMYK colors directly from PDDeviceCMYK ?

```
PDColor color = getGraphicsState().getNonStrokingColor();
PDSeparation colorSpace = (PDSeparation) color.getColorSpace();
float[] rgb = colorSpace.toRGB(color.getComponents());
```

Comment: Have a look at PDSeparation.java. It does `float[] altColor = tintTransform.eval(value);` to get the value in the alternative colorspace. Much of this stuff is private / protected, so you'll need to copy the code.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thanks,  I added break point on altColor after I called colorSpace.toRGB(color.getComponents());, and the result is [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], is that the correct cmyk values? I am not sure, should I pas color.getComponents as a param, this is what PageDrawer is doing at least in getPaint function.

Comment: You were right Tilman, I got the CMYK by copying the code from PDSeperation.java and put it into my function, thanks once again.

Comment: I suggest you answer this yourself. Or ping KenS so that he adds it to his answer. His answer is correct but a bit abstract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Addition to what @KenS said in his first comment, and with the help of @Tilman, you can extract the CMYK colors by overriding protected / private code inside PDSeperation.java, you can do it like this, I am not posting the entire code, but the section to read the colors are posted below

```
private static final int TINT_TRANSFORM = 3;

PDColor color = getGraphicsState().getNonStrokingColor();
COSArray array = (COSArray) color.getColorSpace().getCOSObject();
PDFunction tintTransform = PDFunction.create(array.getObject(TINT_TRANSFORM));
cmykColor = tintTransform.eval(color.getComponents());
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no CMYK colours in a Separation space, its a spot colour, for example a Pantone colour or something like Silver or Gold. You print it using the specific required ink.

In order to print (and display) the content on devices which don't have the required ink, Separation spaces have an Alternate colour space and a method for converting the input ink percentage into that colour space.

In your case the Alternate is DeviceCMYK and there will be a PDF Function which takes 1 input and returns 4 outputs. Given a colour between 0 and 1 of the Separation ink, it will return the equivalent CMYK values.

There are no RGB components for you to recover from the file either, I presume that colorSpace.toRGB() is retrieving the ink value, running the function to convert that to CMYK and then converting the CMYK to RGB. Assuming that pdfbox has a colorSpace.toCMYK() function I would use that instead.

Comment: Actually, I am not reaching any device, I only want to display the values of the colors being used, I didn't find a function colorspace.toCMYK()
I searched on pageDrawer in PDF box and found that they extract the RGB color using code similar to above code which results to
0.003524834 0.0 0.0
I assume the output is the correct RGB colors being using in that graphic state, right?
Edit: pressed post by mistake

Comment: It doesn't matter whether **you** are intending the result for a device. PDF is intended for rendering to a device, and that's why the specification mandates a alternate colour space for /Separation spaces. I don't know anything about PDFBox so I can't help you there, but if your color space has a DeviceCMYK alternate space, then there are on RGB components; none at all. The graphics state will only hold valid RGB components if the current colour space is DeviceRGB, which it isn't. The code you are using looks to me like its doing what I said in my answer Separation->CMYK->RGB.